# WordPress Shortcode Time formatting issue form a variable

Tags: wordpress, datetime, shortcode

I am trying to get the time to display in the 12 hour format but it is constantly showing as 12am instead of the correct time.

```
add_shortcode( 'vc_event_time', 'vc_event_time_render' );

function vc_event_time_render() {
    $start = "{{post_data:_event_start_time}}";
    $str_start = strval($start);
    $new_start = date("h:i a", strtotime($str_start));
    $end = "{{post_data:_event_end_time}}";
    $str_end = strval($end);
    $new_end = date("h:i a", strtotime($str_end));
   return '<div class="vc_gitem-align-center">Event is from '. $new_start .' to     '. $new_end.'.</div>';
}
```

[image: output]

I tried doing a var_dump of the variable which shows string(31) when it should be only string(8).  I most likely missing something obvious, but it is not coming to me what it is.

Comment: What timezone is wp in? Also check the actual time in the database.

Comment: It is in the Eastern Timezone.  The image shows the time when I try to change it and the time without changing it.

Comment: I realize after converting the $start from a string to hex and then examine the hex values the string is actually {{post_data:_event_start_time}} which renders on the page as the time.